# Jupyter Nbextensions doesn't work in Virtual Environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-venv

The trouble: Nbextensions doesn't work in Jupyter in virtual environment.

1. I run existing venv - this stage OK
2. I run command 'pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions' - this stage OK
3. I run command 'jupyter contrib nbextension install --user' - this stage OK
4. I run command 'jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user' - this stage OK, verification OK
5. I run command 'jupyter notebook'
6. I see Jupiter start page, but it is as usual, there is no Nbextensions tab.

What's wrong?